# Marketing Cloud journey builder push email twice

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a question regarding the journey builder. When a customer on checkout and subscribe to the email. at the same time, the user can also create a new account and subscribe with the same email. And the issue is user receives email twice through the same campaign. Is there any way in journey builder to avoid the same email duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to look at your options for the Journey Settings: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5

In your case, you may wish to allow re-entry only after exiting, or not allowing re-entry at all, so that a subscriber does not enter the journey more than once.

There are other options of excluding subscribers who have already been sent an email (exclusion script for example) if you want subscribers to be able to enter your journey multiple times but not receive specific emails in the journey more than once.

Comment: Thanks, @antonio But I have a scenario.                                                                                           I have a question regarding the journey builder. I have multiple journeys in the marketing cloud. I want to restrict Customers to enter in only one journey. Suppose we have two journies in the marketing cloud (JourneyA and JourneyB). When a customer enters in JourneyA He will not subscribe in journeyB. Is there any way in the marketing cloud to avoid the customer resubscribing to another journey if he exists in someone else journey?

Comment: The easiest option available to you is to make use of the Update Contact activity: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_contact_activity_update.htm&type=5

If you add this to the start of your journeys and update a field in your master data extension of Contacts (maybe a field for Journey_A_Entry_Date for example), you can then use decision splits or filters for your journeys so that you can exclude anyone who has entered the other journey. Be aware that the data extension you update needs to be part of your data model in Contact Builder.